# How to call Delete Function of Database Handler class?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to use below given delete function from my Database Handler file.

**Delete Function ( *In DatabaseHandler File* ):**

```
// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

When I am implementing it **in another activity.** like this:

```
String a = Integer.toString(_contactlist.get(position).getID());
            viewHolder.txtid.setText(a.trim());
            viewHolder.txt_name.setText(_contactlist.get(position).getName().trim());
            viewHolder.txt_phone.setText(_contactlist.get(position).getPhoneNumber().trim());

final int temp = position;

Contact pm = db.getContact(temp); //temp is the position of the contact
    db.deleteContact(pm);
```

but when I am using this i am getting an unexpected error i.e.

**LOGCAT :**

```
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at com.parth.targetthebudget.DatabaseHandler.getContact(DatabaseHandler.java:80)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at com.parth.targetthebudget.ViewContact$ListAdapter$2$1.onClick(ViewContact.java:149)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-19 19:21:25.468: W/System.err(304):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**PROBLEM:**

Its is left with only one data in it. and the last data is not at all deleting **but showing this above error**

**EDIT *(getContact(); Method)* :**

```
// Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
}
```

Comment: please post your getContact method too!

Comment: Its crashing in getContact, not deleteContact.  Post the code of that function.

Comment: I have edited my getContact() method in my question.

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor#moveToFirst()` returns a boolean for a reason. If it's false, this means the `Cursor` cannot move to first position (most likely because there is no elements). But you're not checking this return value and doing

```
Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
```

which of course will fail with `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `Cursor` is empty. Also `SQLiteDatabase#query()` never returns `null`, so that null pointer check is not needed.

```
    Contact contact = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    }
    return contact;
```

As a side note: always uses braces `{}`.  You'll save yourself more than one headache. Note that with your old code you would be accessing the `Cursor` (`cursor.getString(0)`) even if it was null (you were just lucky `SQLiteDatabase#query()` does not return `null`) which would raise an NPE.

Comment: Hey! I am still with the same problem its not deleting the last record left in stack. :(

Comment: Sorry I don't see how that's possible. Make sure you cleaned your project and you uploaded the new app successfully to your testing device. Make a `Log` inside the `if (cursor.moveToFirst())` and see if it happens.

Comment: Its Showing **java.lang.NPE** n not catching 'Log' from 'if (cursor.moveToFirst())'

Comment: So, it's **NOT** the same error. Post the whole NPE stacktrace.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35775/discussion-between-parth-sharma-and-m0skit0)